# Why is my serviceworker accessing foreign hosts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I managed to register a service worker on my website(currently only localhost, using a self signed cert and have imported into Trusted Certificates in Chrome 62.0.3202.75). Now my problem is that it fails caching some files, presumably because it's making CORS-requests even though in my 'urlsToCache' list there are only local urls(although in some css files I'm importing from google-fonts).

I've tried foreignFetch, but this also fails... I think I've tried nearly anything there is on the internet, but can't find a solution.

My service worker code:

```
var CACHE_NAME = "stupla-cache-0001";
var urlsToCache = [
  './',
  '/sw.js',
  '/favicon.ico',
  '/stupla-icon-4x.ico',
  '/manifest.json',
  '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 
  '/js/custom.js', 
  '/js/jquery.dlmenu.js', 
  '/js/jquery.js', 
  '/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js', 
  '/js/modernizr.custom.js', 
  '/js/wow.min.js', 
  '/color/default.css', 
  '/css/animate.css', 
  '/css/bootstrap.min.css', 
  '/css/dlmenu.css', 
  '/css/font-awesome.min.css', 
  '/css/overwrite.css',
  '/css/preloader.css',
  '/css/style.css',
  '/css/table.css',
  '/img/mail.png',
  '/img/bg-mac.png', 
  '/img/icons/stupla-icon-2x.ico', 
  '/img/icons/stupla-icon-4x.ico'];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(      // !!! Line 31 !!!
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
    .then(function(cache) {
      console.log('Opened cache');
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  );
});

this.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(resp) {
      return resp || fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.urlurl + ": " + response.type);
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
        });
        return response;
      });
    }).catch(function() {
      return caches.match('/null.dat');
    })
  );
});
```

Chrome console output:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    Promise rejected (async)
    (anonymous) @ sw.js:31
```

Comment: the error you are seeing logged is because at least one of the URLs you are trying to cache is 404 or 5xx.
BTW, you do not need a TLS certificate for localhost :)

Comment: I have tried if any of the files 404 by using a php script looking for every file in the array, which succeeds. Upon your answer, I checked every URL manually via Chrome, no URL 404d. I'm confused beyond imagination right now.

Comment: remove the code to cache the files and see what happens.

Comment: **IMPORTANT NOTE** Tried the website as is in Firefox (v56.0.2) and it works! Without any error messages! Tried it in Chrome and it errord, seems to be an issue with chrome I guess,

Comment: @ChrisLove It gets registered and fails at the `cache.addAll()` function.